# How to check both table having same row values Even Rows are mismatch?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Two table consider tbl1 and tbl2

```
   tbl1 

   Site
   ---------
   101 - Hold
   102 - test

   tbl2

   Site
   ---------
   101 - Hold
   104 - wel
   102 - test
```

I want to check tbl2 data is present in tbl1 . If yes select statement has to return  'Yes' else 'No' ...

```
EXample
If tbl2 is not having "102-test" then also i have to return 'No'
```

How can i achieve this.

Comment: can you please check my updated question

Comment: Do you want one return values -- "yes" or "no" -- for the whole table?  Or one return value per row?

Answer (score 0):

You do this by looking for a non-match and using this information:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
from tbl2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from tbl1 where t1.site = t2.site);
```

The `count(*)` guarantees that exactly one row is returned, containing `yes` or `no`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 CASE EXISTS( SELECT Id FROM tbl2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM tbl1))
      THEN 'Yes'
      ELSE 'No'
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if `tbl2` data exists in `tbl1` and returning back the `site` with value either `Yes` or `No` when `tbl2` exists in `tbl1` or not.

No need to use any aggregate and you have information about all `tbl1` site's - which is what you wanted to achieve (according to your question).

```
SELECT 
    a.site, CASE WHEN b.site IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No END AS value_exists
FROM 
    tbl1 a
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON
        a.site = b.site
```

If you have duplicate values in `tbl1` then you might want to consider adding `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` clause.